# Confused on how to implement an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, implementation

So I was looking at ArrayLists and was confused on how to add elements to the array without expliciting stating people.add(person1) over and over for every object. This code I have currently compiles but doesn't print anything in the console. I reckon my mistake is something with the object constructor and the `people.add(this)`. What am I doing wrong?

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class People {

  int age;
  String name;

  static ArrayList<People> people = new ArrayList<People>();

  public People(String name, int age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    people.add(this);
  }    

  People person1 = new People("Bob", 41);
  People person2 = new People("Arthur", 32);
  People person3 = new People("Tom",18);

  public static void main(String[] args){

    for(People p : people) {
      System.out.println(p.name);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Initialize `person1 ,2, 3` in `main`

Comment: The `person1`, `person2`, and `person3` variables are all instance variables; they'll only be instantiated when an instance of `People` is instantiated. Since you never instantiate a `People` instance inside any called code there will never be any `People` added to the `ArrayList`. You will want to make the variables `static` or move them to local variables inside `main`. Don't keep them where they are, however, as instantiating a `People` instance will attempt to create three more instances—leading to a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: @Slaw it most certainly will him to stackoverflow. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the array list is a `static` variable. The`People` objects you are creating are nonstatic variables that are created only when the constructor is called. You should move the object creation into the `main()` function.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  People person1 = new People("Bob", 41);
  People person2 = new People("Arthur", 32);
  People person3 = new People("Tom",18);

    for(People p : people) {
      System.out.println(p.name);
    }
  }
```

you can read more about static variables [here](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/java-static-class-block-methods-variables/)

Comment: Ah okay thank you. I'm still rusty on difference between static and non-static. Also, why is it that we have to call people.add(this)  and not people.add(Person) since the object being added is Person. What's the "this" really mean?

Comment: `this` is a reference to the *current* object — the object whose method or constructor is being called. You are calling `list#add` inside the constructor, so `people.add(this)` will tell the program to add the current object to the list.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you :)

Comment: @krauser126 If you found this useful, you should mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You have slightly over complicated your codes. For playing with `ArrayList`, you can declare ArrayList within main method and there itself create objects of class People and add people objects in ArrayList. The way you have created those three instances of People class within People class, creation of People object will lead to circular reference leading to `StackOverflowError`.

You should modify your code to something like this, and also note for printing meaningful information for People object, you will need to override toString method from Object class otherwise it will simply print object address which may appear garbage to you.

```
public class People {

    int age;
    String name;

    public People(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("age: %s, name: %s", age, name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<People> people = new ArrayList<People>();

        People person1 = new People("Bob", 41);
        People person2 = new People("Arthur", 32);
        People person3 = new People("Tom", 18);

        people.add(person1);
        people.add(person2);
        people.add(person3);

        people.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Try this and let me know if you face any problems.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class People {

  int age;
  String name;

  People(String name, int age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;


    Main.people.add(this);
  }    

}

public class Main {

  public static ArrayList<People> people = new ArrayList<People>();

  public static void main(String[] args){

  People person1 = new People("Bob", 41);
  People person2 = new People("Arthur", 32);
  People person3 = new People("Tom",18);


    System.out.println(people.size());

    for(People p : people) {
      System.out.println(p.name);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: You can leave the `main` in `People`